# $\det_B(v_1, \dots, v_n) = 0 \implies (v_1, \dots ,v_n) $ are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

It is fairly simple to prove this using the definition of determinant that relies on matrices. But, given the (equivalent) "abstract" definition of a determinant where the determinant relative to a basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is defined as the unique alternating $n$- multilinear form $f$ satisfying $f(e_1,\dots,e_n) = 1$ , how can we go about proving this?

This is what I have for now -

> If we denote each $v_i = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_j^i \cdot e_j$,
>
> $$\det_B(v_1,\dots,v_n) = 0$$
> $$\implies \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}^{} sgn(\sigma) a_1^{\sigma(1)} \cdot a_2^{\sigma(2)} \cdot \dots \cdot a_n^{\sigma(n)} = 0$$
>
> (by using the properties of alternating maps and the way the determinant was defined)

Not really sure how can I go on from here. If anyone has a hint I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you have enough machinery to do something like: to prove the contrapositive, suppose $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ are linearly independent and therefore a basis.  Then there exists an alternating form $g$ satisfying $g(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = 1$, and $g$ must be a scalar multiple of $f$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Wow. That is so neat. I had proved earlier that such an alternating multilinear form is unique, I think I also now need to prove such a function always exists too given a basis.

Comment: @RahulKumar to prove existence: consider the dual basis $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_n$ of $v_1, \dots, v_n$ and put $g(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \varphi_1(x_1) \cdots \varphi_n(x_n)$.

Comment: @Guido I don't think such a $g$ is an _alternating_ multilinear map.

Comment: @RahulKumar whoops, I was thinking about $\varphi_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \varphi_n = \sum_\sigma sgn(\sigma)\varphi_{\sigma(1)}\cdots\varphi_{\sigma(n)}$.

Comment: @RahulKumar How did you construct the determinant in the first place without showing the function exists for the basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$?  My $g$ is just the determinant with respect to the new basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah I see what you mean. My question was if we have such an alternating multilinear function which takes the basis vectors to $1$ and $(v_1, \dots , v_n)$ to $0$, can we conclude $(v_1, \dots , v_n)$ are linearly dependent.
The existence of the initial determinant with respect to $B$ was part of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the discussion in the comments: by the contrapositive, assume linear independence and fix a dual basis $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_n$ of $\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$. Put

$$
g := \varphi_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \varphi_n = \sum_\sigma (-1)^\sigma \varphi_{\sigma(1)}\cdots \varphi_{\sigma(n)}.
$$

This is multilinear since it is a linear combination of multilinear maps, and

$$
g(v_1,\cdots,v_n) = (-1)^{id}\varphi_1(v_1)\cdots \varphi_n(v_n) = 1.
$$

As for antisymmetry, note that if $\tau = (ij)$ then

$$
\begin{align}
g(v_1,\cdots, \overbrace{v_j}^i,\cdots, \overbrace{v_i}^j,\cdots, v_n) &= \sum_\sigma (-1)^\sigma \varphi_{\sigma(1)}(v_1)\cdots \varphi_{\sigma(i)}(v_j) \cdots \varphi_{\sigma(j)}(v_i)\cdots \varphi_{\sigma(n)}(v_n)\\
&= (-1)^\tau\sum_\sigma (-1)^{\tau\sigma} \varphi_{\tau\sigma(1)}(v_1)\cdots    \varphi_{\tau\sigma(n)}(v_n)\\
&= -g(v_1, \dots, v_n).
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand we have that $\operatorname{Mult}(V) \simeq \Bbbk$ since such a map is determined by its image on a fixed ordered basis. Since both $g$ and $\det$ are nonzero, there exists a nonzero scalar $\lambda \in \Bbbk$ such that

$$
g  =\lambda \det
$$

and evaluating in $(v_j)$ yields

$$
1 = \lambda \det(v_1, \dots, v_n),
$$

which in particular says that $\det(v_1,\dots,v_n) \neq 0$.